# Force internet traffic through wifi

Tags: debian, networking, raspberry-pi, routing, route

I currently have a setup where my rpi 3b (raspbian jessie), is connected to two routers, using eth0 and wlan0. I want to using eth0 only to communicate with another device in tha LAN. And i want to use wlan0 for WAN traffic via the router.

- RPI eth0 -> router A -> Device in LAN. (RPI assigned IP in range 10.x.x.x)
- RPI wlan0 -> router B -> any WAN traffic. (RPI assigned static IP 192.168.1.13)

is it enough to use the route command, something like this below?

```
sudo route del default
sudo route add default gw 192.168.1.1 (let's say this is the IP address of the router i want to use for internet)
```

however i was advised to avoid using the route command, since it is overwritten by most network configuration commands.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by route command being overwritten by config,
but you can use **ip** command instead (from iproute* package):

```
sudo ip route replace default via 192.168.1.1
sudo ip route flush cache
```

Both commands manage (view/edit) routing table entries.

A bit of advice - you can have the ethernet interface manually configured
without setting a default gateway on it (just an ip address and manual/dynamic
routing if necessary). If that's not an option you can configure dhcp client
to reject default gateway option on that interface (eth0).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The issue with route, or ip route as you suggested, is that the changes do not seem to be permanent. If i reboot the device, or unplug and plug back the ethernet cable, all goes back as it was, with eth0 being the "preferred" interface and assigned with lowest metric. I am researching on the other 2 options you suggested. Thanks again